# How to sum up the array value of one key by checking the duplication of array value of another key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [linkId] => 1
            [clicksDate] => 1340856000
            [clicksCount] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [linkId] => 1
            [clicksDate] => 1340942400
            [clicksCount] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [linkId] => 1
            [clicksDate] => 1340942400
            [clicksCount] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [linkId] => 2
            [clicksDate] => 1340856000
            [clicksCount] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [linkId] => 2
            [clicksDate] => 1340942400
            [clicksCount] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [linkId] => 2
            [clicksDate] => 1340942400
            [clicksCount] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [linkId] => 3
            [clicksDate] => 1340856000
            [clicksCount] => 0
        )
}
```

Output :

```
Array(

    [0] => Array(  
       [clicksDate] => 1340856000,
       [clicksCount] => 3
     )

    [1] => Array(  
       [clicksDate] => 1340942400,
       [clicksCount] => 7
     )
)
```

The first array having two similar date , Based on the date repeatation , i need to sum the clicks count .Can any one help me to find simple solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the date to a key of an associative array, then sum the clicks as the value, like so:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    if (!isset($result[$value['clicksDate']])) {
        $result[$value['clicksDate']] = 0;
    }
    $result[$value['clicksDate']] += $value['clicksCount'];
}
var_dump($result);
```

See it in action here: http://codepad.org/tJEBTobr

Comment: @SangeethaNarayanaMoorthy Dont forget to click the tick then